# Different GLM Result (R vs. julia)

Tags: r, julia, glm

I ran a basic logistic regression in R and Julia. Despite using the same data I obtained different results. I used the following code:

R:

```
glm(Yi ~ welfare + married + college + agestar + smokernew + wprestar, 
    data=glm_data, family=binomial())

R Output:
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -2.44746    1.02790  -2.381   0.0173 *
welfare     -13.90825  554.61491  -0.025   0.9800  
married      -0.45701    0.37610  -1.215   0.2243  
college      -0.91454    0.54504  -1.678   0.0934 .
agestar       0.07857    0.13986   0.562   0.5743  
smokernew     0.78939    0.45357   1.740   0.0818 .
wprestar     -0.27257    0.11423  -2.386   0.0170 *
```

Julia:

```
glm(Yi ~ welfare + married + college + agestar + smokernew + wprestar,
    glm_data, Binomial(), LogitLink())

Julia Output:
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std.Error   z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -2.44746    1.0279  -2.38104   0.0173
welfare       -9.90825   75.0597 -0.132005   0.8950
married      -0.457005  0.376097  -1.21513   0.2243
college      -0.914541  0.545042  -1.67793   0.0934
agestar      0.0785672  0.139856  0.561774   0.5743
smokernew     0.789386  0.453571   1.74038   0.0818
wprestar      -0.27257  0.114234  -2.38605   0.0170
```

Why?

All coefficients are the same except for the welfare variable. I've checked my data frames and they are the exact same.

Comment: Probably different defaults for handling discrete variables. Post some output. We cannot see your screen.

Comment: And perhaps a summary of the data so we at least know what the `welfare` variable looks like. Is it binary? Coded as categorical? Are there missing values?

Comment: The output is now easier to read. Also the welfare variable is a vector of 1s and 0s of length 3000 with 47 1s.

Comment: I can post the data somewhere if anyone wants to try to replicate this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without looking at your data, I'm going to guess that you have close to complete separation on your response classes on your `welfare` variable. An estimate of (+/-) 13 on the logistic scale is essentially (+/-) infinity, which corresponds to estimated probabilities of zero or one. Julia's estimate of -9.9 is essentially the same, except that it maybe terminates the iterations a bit earlier so returns a slightly smaller value of infinity.

This is known as the [Hauck-Donner phenomenon](https://www.google.com/?q=hauck-donner%20phenomenon) and you can find [questions about it on CrossValidated.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27442/logistic-regression-performance-with-high-number-of-predictors) (the statistics/ML StackExchange site).

Comment: Thanks Hong! That makes complete sense!