# large standard errors in binary logistic regression

Tags: r

I'm working on a dataset in R and I encountered two problems while creating a binary logistic regression model. One problem is that one of the levels of a predictor variable gives very large standard errors. The other is that the subject's ID could not be entered as a random effect despite being transformed into a factor variable.

I included the regression model below

```
glm(formula = DO ~ phase + (1 | participant), family = binomial, 
    data = dative)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.79715   0.00008   0.20101   0.25951   0.98949  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)            0.4595     0.2129   2.159   0.0309 *  
phase2                 2.9146     0.5022   5.804 6.47e-09 ***
phase3                19.1065  1070.0643   0.018   0.9858    
phase4                 3.4323     0.7453   4.605 4.12e-06 ***
1 | participantTRUE        NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 282.68  on 444  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 187.66  on 441  degrees of freedom
AIC: 195.66

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18
```

I added a reproducible version of the dataset

> dput(dative) structure(list(participant = c("A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A101", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A107", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A103", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A102", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A104", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A109", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A108", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A105", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "A106", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N105", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N105", "N105", "N105", "N105", "N105", "N105", "N105", "N105", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N105", "N105", "N105", "N105", "N105", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N102", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N107", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N101", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N104", "N105", "N105", "N105", "N105", "N105", "N105", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N106", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N108", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103", "N103"), speaker = c("L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2"), gender = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male" ), Age = c(38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 19, 19, 19, 19, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27 ), pscores = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "5", "5", "5", "5", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "3", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11"), phase = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), condition = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), trialnumber = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 6, 14, 16, 18, 22, 24, 30, 34, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 18, 20, 34, 38, 4, 10, 16, 18, 24, 26, 30, 32, 38, 2, 8, 10, 12, 14, 18, 24, 26, 38, 2, 6, 12, 14, 18, 20, 22, 34, 38, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 20, 28, 36, 38, 4, 6, 10, 14, 16, 22, 26, 28, 36, 6, 10, 14, 18, 26, 28, 34, 36, 38, 6, 8, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 6, 8, 12, 18, 22, 24, 28, 30, 8, 10, 12, 18, 24, 26, 28, 30, 38, 16, 18, 24, 26, 28, 30, 36, 38, 2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 24, 28, 36, 38, 2, 4, 8, 10, 14, 16, 24, 30, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 6, 10, 12, 14, 16, 32, 34, 38, 4, 6, 10, 12, 20, 22, 26, 30, 32, 6, 8, 20, 22, 26, 28, 30, 32, 38, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA ), ItemType = c("EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP", "EXP"), DO = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ), ResponseMotivation = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SP_detection = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -445L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

My problems are really easy but since I'm a beginner in R, I could not solve them.

I would be so grateful if someone could help.

Comment: Please don't upload code, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: `glm()` doesn’t support random effects. You will need to use something like `glmer()` from the {lme4} package.

Comment: thanks a lot zephryl for spotting this mistake! :D

Comment: Greetings! It is generally preferable to provide a reproducible version of your data. One way of doing that is sharing either the `dput` of your data or `dput` of a subset of your data. You can learn more about how to do this here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340674/how-can-a-se-be-above-1000-in-a-multilevel-logistic-regression/18341504#18341504 ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864155/different-glm-result-r-vs-julia/28868486#28868486 ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596160/why-am-i-getting-algorithm-did-not-converge-and-fitted-prob-numerically-0-or/8596547#8596547 ;

Comment: 442 observations is a really small data set ... ??

Comment: @Shawn Hemelstrand thanks for your comment, I added a reproducible version of my data.

Comment: Hi Ben Bolker, thanks a lot for the useful links! the data is not that small I admit, I think I mistakenly equated the number of participants (N =17) with the size of data while I should have considered the number of observations to estimate the data size.

Comment: @BenBolker thanks for the advice, I used the "brglm" package and it solved the separation problem in my data. However, how can I keep the random effects when using the "brglm" function?